# Pb with a C programm : double free or corruption (!prev)

Tags: c, linux, sdl, fractals

A few years ago, when Benoit Mandelbrot died, I decided to make a small program to calculate and see his famous fractal set. I did it many years ago before (with turbo pascal language) - At this period, the calculus took one night. So I decided to learn a little of C language. With code::blocks and the SDL Library (and many helps), I finally wrote a program were I could see the set, and zoom inside with my mouse.
It worked good, I was under windows. Instead of one night of calculus, it took 5 seconds to do the same job.

Recently I decided to discover linux, installed the same IDE with the SDL,. The program is compiling OK. It begins to run, and suddenly, when I use the mouse (left-clic up and down to select the new squared area where to zoom in), the program stops.

The message is :

```
double free or corruption (!prev)
```

The strange thing is that it never happened when I ran the code under windows. So here is a mysterious thing for me. I don't know what means double **free** or **corruption** here.

For a better help you could eventually send me, I join the code of the program (not perfect). Maybe someone could find where the problem is ...
The program was writen to be seen on a 1680x1050 pxl screen.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
//#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>

#define MAXITERATIONS 2000
#define CONST_DIVERGENCE 4

#define LONGUEUR_ECRAN 1680 //ajout d'une zone d'information et d'interaction de 630 pixels de large à droite de l'image.
#define LARGEUR_ECRAN 1050  // côté du carré où l'image est calculée.


int i  , j ; /* i variable écran qui parcourt les abscisses entre 0 et LARGEUR_ECRAN
                j les ordonnées entre 0 et LARGEUR_ECRAN */
int n ,t ; // itérations pour le calcul de convergence
int color,color1,color2,color3 ; //variable pour la couleur

int continuer = 1;
int recalculer = 1;
int recommencer = 1;

double XDEBUT = -2.05; // coordonnées du point de départ en haut à gauche du carré du plan complexe
double YDEBUT = -1.35;
double DELTA = 2.7 ; // longueur du côté du carré du plan complexe au départ
double xC =0 , yC = 0 ; // coordonnées du point du plan où on effectue les calculs
double xZ  , yZ ; // coordonnées pour le calcul de la convergence
double xT = 0 ; // valeur temporaire d'allocation

double xTemp1 =0, yTemp1 = 0 ;
double xTemp2 =0, yTemp2 = 0 ;

int xTemoinDebut =1065; //variables pour positionner les cadres dans le Mandel témoin
int yTemoinDebut =15;   //
int deltaTemoin =600;   //

int x_1 , y_1;          //variables pour positionner le cadre de zoom dans le grand Mandel
int x_2 , y_2;          //
int xdebut , ydebut ;   //
int delta;              //

void placerPoint(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint32 pixel);
void petitMandel ();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (recommencer == 1)
    {
        recommencer = 0;
        recalculer =1;
        continuer =1;
        double XDEBUT = -2.05; // coordonnées du point de départ en haut à gauche du carré du plan complexe
        double YDEBUT = -1.35;
        double DELTA = 2.7 ; // longueur du côté du carré du plan complexe au départ

        int xTemoinDebut =1065; //variables pour positionner les cadres dans le Mandel témoin
        int yTemoinDebut =15;   //
        int deltaTemoin =600;   //

        double xC =0 , yC = 0 ; // coordonnées du point du plan où on effectue les calculs
        double xZ  , yZ ; // coordonnées pour le calcul de la convergence
        double xT = 0 ; // valeur temporaire d'allocation
        double xTemp1 =0, yTemp1 = 0 ;
        double xTemp2 =0, yTemp2 = 0 ;
        double tableauX [LARGEUR_ECRAN]= {0};   //tableau pour enregistrer les coordonnées réelles où on calcule
        double tableauY [LARGEUR_ECRAN] = {0};  //


        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL,*rectangle=NULL/*,*texte = NULL*/;
        // SDL_Event event;
        SDL_Rect position;
        ecran = SDL_SetVideoMode(LONGUEUR_ECRAN,LARGEUR_ECRAN, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_FULLSCREEN); // mode vidéo : écran complet
        SDL_LockSurface(ecran);
        //   SDL_FillRect(ecran, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 0, 0, 0)); // remplissage de l'écran en noir
        //  TTF_Font *police = NULL;
        //  SDL_Color couleurBleue = {0,0,255};
        //  TTF_Init();

        // test d'erreur d'initialisation
        /*   if (TTF_Init () == -1)
               {
                   fprintf(stderr, "Erreur d'initialisation de TTF_Init : %s \n",TTF_GetError ());
                   exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
               }*/

        /* TTF_Font *police = NULL;
         SDL_Color couleurBleue = {0,0,255};
         police = TTF_OpenFont("ankecall.ttf",20);                                                                                                                                    police = TTF_OpenFont ("angelina.ttf",65);
         texte  = TTF_RenderText_Blended (police, "Voyage chez Mandelbrot ", couleurBleue);
         while (continuer)
             {
                 SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
                     switch(event.type)
                     {
                         case SDL_QUIT:
                             continuer = 0;
                         break;
                     }

             position.x = 1060;
             position.y = 630;
             SDL_BlitSurface (texte, NULL, ecran, &position);
             SDL_Flip(ecran);
             }
         SDL_FreeSurface(texte);
         TTF_CloseFont(police);
         TTF_Quit ();
        */

        petitMandel(); //commande pour calculer un petit mandel témoin et un trait rouge

        while (recalculer == 1)
        {
            for ( j = 0 ; j < LARGEUR_ECRAN ; j ++) // balayage vertical
            {
                yC = YDEBUT + (DELTA * j)/LARGEUR_ECRAN;
                tableauY[j] = yC;
            }
            for ( i = 0 ; i < LARGEUR_ECRAN ; i ++) // balayage horizontal
            {
                xC = XDEBUT + (DELTA * i)/LARGEUR_ECRAN;
                tableauX [i] = xC;
            }

            for ( j = 0 ; j < LARGEUR_ECRAN ; j ++) // balayage vertical
            {
                yC = YDEBUT + (DELTA * j)/LARGEUR_ECRAN;
                for ( i = 0 ; i < LARGEUR_ECRAN ; i ++) // balayage horizontal
                {
                    xC = XDEBUT + (DELTA * i)/LARGEUR_ECRAN;
                    n = 0 ; // initialisation du compteur de calcul
                    xZ = 0 ;
                    yZ = 0 ;
                    xT = 0 ;
                    while ( xZ*xZ + yZ*yZ < CONST_DIVERGENCE && n < MAXITERATIONS)  /* boucle de calcul
                elle s'arretera si xZ²+yZ² >= 4 ou si on a atteint le maximum d'itérations*/
                    {
                        xT = xZ ;// variable temporaire pour le calcul de yZ
                        xZ = xZ*xZ - yZ*yZ + xC ;
                        yZ = 2*yZ*xT + yC ;
                        n ++;
                    }

                    if (n< MAXITERATIONS)                                         // On est en dehors de l'ensemble : mettre en gris
                        placerPoint(ecran,i,j,SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format,n,n,n));
                    else                                                          // On est dans l'ensemble : mettre en noir.
                        placerPoint(ecran,i,j,SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format,0,0,0));
                }
            }
            SDL_UnlockSurface(ecran);
            SDL_Flip(ecran);

            recalculer = 0;

            //Gestion des choix:
            SDL_Event event;
            while (continuer & (recalculer == 0))
            {
                SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
                switch(event.type)
                {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    continuer = 0;
                    break;

                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)  //si clic gauche enfoncé
                    {
                        position.x = event.button.x;
                        position.y = event.button.y;
                        xTemp1 = tableauX [position.x];
                        yTemp1 = tableauY [position.y];
                        x_1 = position.x;
                        y_1 = position.y;
                    }
                    break;

                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)  //si clic gauche relaché
                    {
                        position.x = event.button.x;
                        position.y = event.button.y;
                        xTemp2 = tableauX [position.x];
                        yTemp2 = tableauY [position.y];
                        x_2 = position.x;
                        y_2 = position.y;

                        if (xTemp1 <xTemp2)
                        {
                            XDEBUT = xTemp1;
                            xdebut = x_1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            XDEBUT = xTemp2;
                            xdebut = x_2;
                        }
                        if (yTemp1<yTemp2)
                        {
                            YDEBUT = yTemp1;
                            ydebut = y_1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            YDEBUT = yTemp2;
                            ydebut = y_2;
                        }
                        if (fabs(xTemp1-xTemp2)<fabs(yTemp1-yTemp2))
                        {
                            DELTA = fabs(yTemp1-yTemp2);
                            delta = fabs(y_1-y_2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DELTA = fabs(xTemp1-xTemp2);
                            delta = fabs(x_1-x_2);
                        }
                        // dessin du cadre blanc pour zoomer dans l'image principale
                        rectangle = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, 1, delta, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Allocation du point
                        position.x = xdebut ; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                        position.y = ydebut ;
                        SDL_FillRect(rectangle, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255,255,255)); // Remplissage du point en gris.
                        SDL_BlitSurface(rectangle, NULL, ecran, &position); // Collage du point sur l'écran
                        SDL_Flip(ecran);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle);

                        rectangle = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE,delta, 1, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Allocation du point
                        position.x = xdebut ; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                        position.y = ydebut ;
                        SDL_FillRect(rectangle, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255,255,255)); // Remplissage du point en gris.
                        SDL_BlitSurface(rectangle, NULL, ecran, &position); // Collage du point sur l'écran
                        SDL_Flip(ecran);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle);

                        rectangle = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, 1, delta, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Allocation du point
                        position.x = xdebut + delta; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                        position.y = ydebut ;
                        SDL_FillRect(rectangle, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255,255,255)); // Remplissage du point en gris.
                        SDL_BlitSurface(rectangle, NULL, ecran, &position); // Collage du point sur l'écran
                        SDL_Flip(ecran);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle);

                        rectangle = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, delta, 1, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Allocation du point
                        position.x = xdebut ; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                        position.y = ydebut + delta;
                        SDL_FillRect(rectangle, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255,255,255)); // Remplissage du point en gris.
                        SDL_BlitSurface(rectangle, NULL, ecran, &position); // Collage du point sur l'écran
                        SDL_Flip(ecran);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle);

                        //dessin du cadre dans le mandelbrot témoin

                        xTemoinDebut = floor(xdebut*deltaTemoin/1050) + xTemoinDebut;
                        yTemoinDebut = floor(ydebut*deltaTemoin/1050) + yTemoinDebut;
                        deltaTemoin = floor(delta*deltaTemoin/1050);

                        rectangle = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, 1, deltaTemoin, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Allocation du point
                        position.x = xTemoinDebut ; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                        position.y = yTemoinDebut ;
                        SDL_FillRect(rectangle, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255,255,255)); // Remplissage du point en gris.
                        SDL_BlitSurface(rectangle, NULL, ecran, &position); // Collage du point sur l'écran
                        SDL_Flip(ecran);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle);

                        rectangle = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, deltaTemoin, 1, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Allocation du point
                        position.x = xTemoinDebut ; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                        position.y = yTemoinDebut ;
                        SDL_FillRect(rectangle, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255,255,255)); // Remplissage du point en gris.
                        SDL_BlitSurface(rectangle, NULL, ecran, &position); // Collage du point sur l'écran
                        SDL_Flip(ecran);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle);

                        rectangle = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, 1, deltaTemoin, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Allocation du point
                        position.x = xTemoinDebut + deltaTemoin; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                        position.y = yTemoinDebut ;
                        SDL_FillRect(rectangle, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255,255,255)); // Remplissage du point en gris.
                        SDL_BlitSurface(rectangle, NULL, ecran, &position); // Collage du point sur l'écran
                        SDL_Flip(ecran);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle);

                        rectangle = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, deltaTemoin, 1, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Allocation du point
                        position.x = xTemoinDebut ; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                        position.y = yTemoinDebut + deltaTemoin;
                        SDL_FillRect(rectangle, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format, 255,255,255)); // Remplissage du point en gris.
                        SDL_BlitSurface(rectangle, NULL, ecran, &position); // Collage du point sur l'écran
                        SDL_Flip(ecran);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle);

                        recalculer = 1;
                    }
                    break;

                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                        continuer = 0 ;
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_r)
                    {
                        recommencer = 1 ;
                        recalculer = 0;
                        continuer =0;
                    }
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_s)
                        SDL_SaveBMP(ecran , "Mandel_50.bmp" ); // Enregistrement de l'image dans un fichier .bmp

                    break;
                }
            }
            SDL_FreeSurface(rectangle); // Libération de la surface
        }
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
void petitMandel ()
{
    int x=0,y=0;
    SDL_Surface *ecran  ;
    ecran = SDL_GetVideoSurface();
    SDL_LockSurface(ecran);

    // trait rouge à droite de l'image
    for (j=5; j<=1044; j++)
    {
        x = LARGEUR_ECRAN +5 ;
        y = j ;
        placerPoint(ecran,x,y,SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format,200,0,0));
    }
    SDL_Flip(ecran);


//  instructions pour placer un petit Mandelbrot témoin dans la fenêtre "interactive"
    for ( j = 0 ; j < 600 ; j ++) // balayage vertical
    {
        yC = YDEBUT + (DELTA * j)/600;
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 600 ; i ++) // balayage horizontal
        {
            xC = XDEBUT + (DELTA * i)/600;
            n = 0 ; // initialisation du compteur de calcul
            xZ = 0 ;
            yZ = 0 ;
            xT = 0 ;
            while ( xZ*xZ + yZ*yZ < CONST_DIVERGENCE && n < 500)  /* boucle de calcul
                elle s'arretera si xZ²+yZ² >= 4 ou si on a atteint le maximum d'itérations*/
            {
                xT = xZ ;// variable temporaire pour le calcul de yZ
                xZ = xZ*xZ - yZ*yZ + xC ;
                yZ = 2*yZ*xT + yC ;
                n ++;
            }
            if (n< 500)
            {
                x = i + 1065 ; //  Coordonnées du point à placer
                y = j + 15;
                color = floor (255-255*log(1+n*255/500)/log(256)); // calcul pour un dégradé plus progressif*/
                placerPoint(ecran,x,y,SDL_MapRGB(ecran->format,color,color,color));
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_UnlockSurface(ecran);
    SDL_Flip(ecran);
}

void placerPoint(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y, Uint32 pixel)
{
    int bpp = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;

    Uint8 *p = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * bpp;

    switch(bpp)
    {
    case 1:
        *p = pixel;
        break;
    case 2:
        *(Uint16 *)p = pixel;
        break;
    case 3:
        if(SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN)
        {
            p[0] = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            p[1] = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            p[2] = pixel & 0xff;
        }
        else
        {
            p[0] = pixel & 0xff;
            p[1] = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            p[2] = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        *(Uint32 *)p = pixel;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your answers.

The proposition of user5071535 is a very good solution. I have no more stops of the program ! Thank you so much. The program runs even better than before and I can "zoom" inside the image much more. When it stopped before, I thought it was because of the lack of precision due to the limits of the digits for the 'double' numbers. Now I can explore new areas.

I also tried the "assert" proposition by ooga, but I have a complilation problem with this command (but I am not a specialist). I try again tomorrow !

JP

Comment: Hello again. Adding #include <assert.h> and the 6 different assert commands, I could not see the difference for the moment.  Thanks again for helping me to debug this program !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're freeing your SDL_Surface pointer "rectangle" once extra on line 309. If you comment that line out it runs fine.

When the code gets into the "SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP" case of your switch statement, it frees the rectangle, then on line 309 it's freed again.

Answer (score 0):

You are overrunning tableauX (and possibly tableauY, if given a chance). Put asserts before them:

```
assert(j < LARGEUR_ECRAN);
tableauY[j] = yC;
```

Put an assert before all accesses (there are 6 in your program).

I did this and the following assertion failed

```
assert(position.x < LARGEUR_ECRAN)
xTemp1 = tableauX [position.x];
```

That the assertion failed means that position.x is >= LARGEUR_ECRAN. In fact it was 1243, whereas LARGEUR_ECRAN is 1050. Note that the failure will not necessarily occur on the first out-of-bounds access, which is why it didn't happen as soon as position.x reached 1050.

Also note that it's possible to run "successfully" (even with the bug) on one system while crashing on another.

EDIT: Actually, user5071535 seems to have found a more likely source for your error message, but I may have uncovered a different bug here.

Answer (score 0):

Every free() on unallocated pointer or in a pointer different of NULL will return this error. Certify yourself if pointer its already allocated or is equal to NULL before any try of free(). Anyway, any try to work in an unallocated pointer or improperly/insufficient allocated will return this error. The fact of under Windows the things happens differently, its only a question of "lucky": Bad codes will fail at any plattform on an "random" time inevitably. Sorry for bad english.